# Access denied for admin page, after moving site from sub-folder to root folder

Tags: commerce, 7

Not able to access administration site after moving files from sub-directory to root folder.

With the help of google search, I have made below changes in settings.php under default folder, but that also didn't helped.
$base_url = 'http://example.com'; //Changed to site name

Actually base_url is commented in my settings.php file, I have tried enabling it.

Drupal version: 7

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I was using url as ?q=admin instead of ?q=user url.